# java - how to modify the string representation of an enum inside an override of its toString() function?

Tags: java, enums, overriding

I have the following enum :

```
public enum Rank{
   FIRST,
   SECOND
}
```

Whenever a `toString()` function is called on an enum (or its used inside a string literal), I want **FIRST_RANK** returned (instead of the string '**FIRST**', as is default). If I override the `toString()` function like :

```
@Override
public String toString(){
  return this.toString() + "_RANK";
}
```

But this would obviously lead to recursion. The problem is that I need to use the default `toString()` implementation of enums, and there is no superclass of enums whose `toString()` I can call.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Whenever you want the *name* of that enum instance, you should use the [**`name()`**](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/lang/Enum.html#name%28%29) method. In your example:

```
@Override public String toString() {
  return this.name() + "_RANK";
}
```

Comment: Well noticed. Did you also notice that EVERY answer until now has the same mistake? It did surprise me. It must have been the question that induced this mistake!

Answer (score 2):

Can you use the [name()](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/6/docs/api/java/lang/Enum.html#name%28%29) method ?

```
@Override public String toString() {
  return this.name() + "_RANK";
}
```

From the doc:

> Returns the name of this enum constant, exactly as declared in its
>   enum declaration. Most programmers should use the toString() method in
>   preference to this one, as the toString method may return a more
>   user-friendly name. This method is designed primarily for use in
>   specialized situations where correctness depends on getting the exact
>   name, which will not vary from release to release.

Answer (score 1):

```
@Override
public toString(){
  return super.toString() + "_RANK";
}
```

Comment: Thanks. What's super in this case ?.. enums have no super class ?

Comment: @Daud, in Java, every class except `Object` has a superclass. The superclass for enums is `Enum`.

Answer (score 1):

try

```
@Override
public toString(){
  return super.toString() + "_RANK";
}
```

Answer (score 1):

add this in your enum

```
 @Override 
 public String toString() {   
       return this.name() + "_RANK"; 
 }
```

toString() should return **String**.

Answer (score 1):

Instead of directly using the name, I'd rather do it this way:

```
@Override public String toString() {   
    return super.toString() + "_RANK"; 
}
```

Even though it results exactly the same as using `this.name()` in this case... But in my opinion this better reflects the object oriented programming in this case.